# Nuxt link failing with graphQL (apollo); uncaught TypeError

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, vue-apollo

There appears to be an issue with my graphQL query, as the template renders but the `nuxt-link` fails. It just shows the `catrule.ruleid` text, but is not in a link format.

Template:

```
<li v-for="catrule in cat_rulesetCollection">
    <nuxt-link :to="`/cat-rule/` + catrule.ruleid">{{ catrule.ruleid }}</nuxt-link>
</li>
```

Apollo:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
export default {
    apollo: {
        cat_rulesetCollection: gql` {
            cat_rulesetCollection(populate:1) {
                ruleid
                }
            }`
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at VueComponent.observe (nuxt-link.client.js?4e55:62)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how backticks work inside double quote but I would have done something like this :

```
<nuxt-link :to=`/cat-rule/${catrule.ruleid}`>{{ catrule.ruleid }}</nuxt-link>
```

Or

```
<nuxt-link :to="`/cat-rule/` + {{ catrule.ruleid }} ">{{ catrule.ruleid }}</nuxt-link>
```